# How to block specific human looking user agent in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have been having a few problems with spam recently and bots registering and all these anti captcha systems do not seem to be working.

I have analyzed my access logs and discovered the user agents are not used by humans maybe because they are old... But also noticed that there has been some HEAD / GET / POST / attacks also coming in to the web server as well using the exact same string on user agents. Possibly booters using the same user agents as spam/add bots.

> 216.151.139.172 - - [24/Mar/2013:00:58:20 +0000] "GET /index.php?action=verificationcode;vid=register;rand=12c64196f4558b2dff00db7ed3ee8ad9
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 2189 "index.php?action=register" "Mozilla/4.0
>   (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR
>   1.1.4322)" "-"

In nginx without blocking all user agents, is there anyway to just block this string contained in the useragent so these bots can stop registering and advertising.

> "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
if ($http_user_agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)") {
  return 444; # 444 is a special nginx status code that's useful in fighting attack
}
```

But that user agent string is valid, which means that you could block some legit visits as well.

I'd suggest you try ip based access control. See http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule for setting that up. It's better in my opinion.

Comment: I understand that.. I checked all my logs and found no actual real users with that user agent.. I understand its valid, says internet explorer 7/8 windows XP.. TBH I doubt many people use that..
I will add a return 445 or something and create a 445 page informing them that they have been detected as a bot, please contact admin.. I  dunno how to do it with access control as you would have to add every IP.. I just trying to block these specific bots, they are advertising dating websites, office software and porn.. Need to get rid of them.. Losing a few members is worth it.

Comment: Dunno lol... I just been looking at a few bots, and their user agents differ there is loads of them :( not good.. But I checked them all and no legit users use them.. Cause I have a shoutbox and no connections are made to that showing its a bot as there would be loads of requests coming from their also..
What's the best way to add multiple user agents?
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you considered routing your traffic through CloudFlare to mitigate some of these spammers?

Comment: It's hard to scale a user-agent based rule in nginx alone: You can use regex to match a number of user agents in the if block. Other than that, you may have to use scripts (php, ruby, python) for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* (Windows 95|Windows 98|wget|curl|libwww-perl) ) {
return 403;
}
```

For much information on this  check below link 
https://www.nxtcloud.io/block-unwanted-user-agent-traffic-on-nginx/